# Broadcom GNSS 4752 not working on Windows 10, need driver

Tags: windows, drivers

I have a ASUS Vivotab M81C tablet, which have a BCM4752 GPS chip, it was working on stock Windows 8.1, but after I clean installed Windows 10 (32-bit), it do not work, I managed to install the Windows 8.1 driver from official ASUS website, and it says "This device cannot start (Code 10)", I think it must caused by the incompatible driver, but I cannot find one, please anyone help me, thanks!

EDIT: Also need InvenSense 6500 driver.

Comment: You could try [this](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds104652) one. It is from a Lenovo support page, but it is the driver for the Broadcom  4752/ Windows 10 32-bit so it should still work.

Comment: for me this driver also works for my Toshiba Encore Tablet. try the driver again.

Comment: @n8te The Lenovo site you mentioned requires a serial number for download.